# How do I convert string date to datetime?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

The dates that I have in a data frame are formatted like this:

Apr 5, 2010.

How can I convert them to datetime?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
date_time_str = 'Sep 28, 2019'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%m %d, %Y')
print(date_time_obj)
```

But I know this is wrong.

(I've tried looking for similar questions on here, but most people have their string dates formatted like 05-05-2010.)

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%b %d, %Y')`

Comment: if it is 'Sep 8, 2019', datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%b %-d, %Y'); if it is 'Sep 08, 2019', datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%b %d, %Y')

Comment: As people already said, %m is the month in integer format, %b is month in 3 characters format. Using the correct notation you will get: 2019-09-28 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

The following code will produce a new datetime object with the values you would like.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = 'Sep 28, 2019'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%b %d, %Y')
print(date_time_obj)
print(type(date_time_obj))  # verify object type
```